# Service gets restarted when app is reopened

Tags: android, android-service

My app's `Service` starts as soon as the app is launched for the first time. Once it gets started, I don't want app to restart it when it is reopened. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Store a boolean on `SharedPreferences` and prevent the `Service` from running again

Comment: where can i put the condition for sharedpreference checking

Comment: Look at Bojan's answer

Comment: so have you figured it out or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test to see if the service is already running.
I expect somewhere in the Android SDK you can interrogate the running services and see if it's already running.

Someone else will likely have a better idea though, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Read SharedPreferences once your Activity starts and check if you still need the Service

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefsName", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean doINeedService = prefs.getBoolean("doINeedService", true);
if(doINeedService){
   startService(...);
}
```

Once the service is done, put a boolean into `SharedPreferences` like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefsName", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putBoolean("doINeedService", false);
edit.commit();
```

Comment: This answer is good if you need to know if the `Service` is currently running. I think he just wants to detect if the service already ran. Simple value in `SharedPreferences` might do and you do not need the extra permission.